# How do i know which operations transformed a signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals, transform

I am doing an undergrad assignment and one of the exercises is as follows:

Given the following signal $x(t)$:

[image]

and another signal $y(t)$ which was transformed from $x(t)$:

[image]

Describe $y(t)$ in function of $x(t)$ using signal transformations (compression/expansion, time offset, etc).

*My strategy:*
I know there are at least two operations: amplification (multiplying x(t) for a factor of 2) and delaying the signal by 2 seconds $x(t-2)$. I thought it would be $y(t) = 2x(t-2)$ but it is wrong and i don't know why. If someone could please clearify i would be thankful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's not much to teach here: You have a mistake, and you seem clever enough to find it yourself! Try to actually draw the $y(t)$ you're proposing by putting in $t=-0.5, 0, +0.5, +1, +1.5,\ldots$ and look whether it actually produces the plot you need. Don't cheat, actually do the calculations for these points.

Comment: Thanks, not trying to cheat at all because i'm fascinated to this subject :)

Comment: ah :) that's not what I meant. I just remembered when I was a student, and I would have been very prone to just "do it in my head", i.e. do the shifting as I *thougt* I had written down. What I meant with "don't cheat" is "don't be smart, actually take $t$, subtract 2, look up the value at that point in $x(t)$, multiply that with 2, and mark the point in your graph", instead of doing what you "think" you're doing correctly (i.e., shifting and scaling the whole curve)

Comment: Oh i see! Thank you for the advice :) About the answer, i've plotted $2x(t-2)$ and it is clearly wrong because i have now a peak of $4$ at $t=0$ but it still goes to $0$ at $t=2$. Can you please give me a hint so signal reaches $0$ at $t=4$?

Comment: I don't think you need the hint; you are listing valid operations, and there's one you haven't used, so hm, try that?

Comment: Ok, after some tries i came up with $y(t) = 2x(\frac{t}{2} - 4)$. Can you please confirm if i am correct?

Comment: What i thought is that i could first expand the signal by 2 (so the $t/2$), then delay it by 4 seconds and then amplify by 2.

Comment: Why do you need *me* to verify it? Just draw your solution's plot and verify yourself. I'm no better at drawing plots than you are.